# Formatting string with microseconds using DateTime::createFromFormat

Tags: php

I have the following date from influxdb: `2015-07-23T20:15:12.630199712Z`

I am trying to format it to just show the hours, minutes and seconds.

```
$date = \DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u\Z", '2015-07-23T20:15:12.630199712Z');
if($date  === false) {
    die('yes');
}
```

Logically that should work... but it returns false. I have tried about ten other different combinations but alas, none of them worked. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Your microseconds are 3 digits too long

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't notice that. Thanks!

Comment: As Rizier123 pointed out, all timestamps from InfluxDB are in nanoseconds.